# iOS with monotouch upload wav file fails

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, wav

I'm writing an iOS app with monotouch.
I'm recording a sound file via the AVrecorder. I create a working wav file(which I check).
I want to send it to my server by passing it as a byte array (seems to be the best way)
The problem is that the file passed to the server is corrupted.
This is how I convert wav to byte []. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

(I iterate to find the files size once and than copy everything. The reason I do this is that the GetProperty returns a wrong size of file).

```
string path = GlobalData.UserDefaults.StringForKey(GlobalData.HeykuSoundPathDefault);
AudioFile song = AudioFile.Open(path,AudioFilePermission.Read,AudioFileType.WAVE);
byte [] audioBuffer = new byte[4000000];

int copied = 0;
int offset = 0;

while(true)
{
  copied = song.Read(offset,audioBuffer,0,4096,false);

   if(copied == -1)
   {
     break;
   }
   else
   {
     offset += copied;
     Console.WriteLine(offset);
   }
}

audioBuffer = new byte[offset];
copied = song.Read(0,audioBuffer,0,offset,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply using streams? Something like this:

```
        using (var fileReader = new StreamReader("filename_here"))
        {
            using (var webStream = webClient.OpenWrite("http://www.myuploader.com"))
            {
                fileReader.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(webStream);
            }
        }
```

The above method should copy the whole file including the Wave headers. I suspect the AudioFile could be returning you pure PCM audio which will not include headers. This is an example of a header writer function:

```
    private void WriteHeader()
    {
        this.writer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        // chunk ID
        this.writer.Write('R');
        this.writer.Write('I');
        this.writer.Write('F');
        this.writer.Write('F');

        this.writer.Write(this.ByteCount);
        this.writer.Write('W');
        this.writer.Write('A');
        this.writer.Write('V');
        this.writer.Write('E');

        this.writer.Write('f');
        this.writer.Write('m');
        this.writer.Write('t');
        this.writer.Write(' ');

        this.writer.Write((int)16);
        this.writer.Write((short)1);

        this.writer.Write((short)this.ChannelCount);
        this.writer.Write((int)this.SampleRate);
        this.writer.Write((int)this.SampleRate*2);
        this.writer.Write((short)2);
        this.writer.Write((short)this.BitsPerSample);
        this.writer.Write('d');
        this.writer.Write('a');
        this.writer.Write('t');
        this.writer.Write('a');
        this.writer.Write((int)this.byteCount);
    }
```

More info on the file format: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

As for reading the data from the AudioFile, this would probably work better:

```
        var song = AudioFile.Open(path,AudioFilePermission.Read,AudioFileType.WAVE); 
        var audioBuffer = new byte[song.Length];

        int copied = 0;

        while (copied < audioBuffer.Length)
        {
            copied += song.Read (copied, audioBuffer, copied, 4096, false);
        }
```